# How to get a users wallet address from MetaMask onto server-side/mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, web3js, metamask

After the user makes an account they are prompted to share their address via MetaMask.

I'm able to get their address to show up in the browser console, but I need to get it to the server so I can store it in mongoDB.

**This is the function I'm using to retrieve the address on the users browser:**

```
async function loginWithMetaMask() {
    const accounts = await window.ethereum.request({method: 'eth_requestAccounts'}).catch((e) => {
    console.error(e.message);})
    window.userWalletAddress = accounts[0]
    userWallet.innerText = window.userWalletAddress
    console.log(accounts);
}
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just send it as string into the db via api or socket
Example using axios

```
axios.post("server.com/get-wallet",{walletAddrrss:window.userWalletAddress});
```

Comment: How do I tell the server to receive this data?

Comment: You just create api for this in the sever

Comment: 'router.post('/post',function(req,res){
    let address = req.body.address;
    console.log("address = "+address);
    res.end("yes");
}); 'I've tried using this but it doesn't work either

Comment: Send it as get request if you didn't setup handling post request in your backend